# ReactJS: Props Not Passing When Child Component Is Subclass of another Class

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, jsx

File1.tsx

```
class abc extends <abcProps, abcstate>
{
   constructor(){...}
}

class def extends abc {
   constructor(){
       super(props)
   }
}

export default{
  def_var: (props) => React.createElement(def, props)
}
```

File2.tsx

```
class xyz extends React.Component<xyzProps, xyzState> {
  //I want to make def the child of this classi.e xyz
  render(){
    return
      <div>
        <def .../>
      </div>
  } 
}
```

I have made a subclass child of another component, and the methods in parent class abc are not functioning properly.

Comment: i'd reckon that it is not advisable to use classical `inheritance` in React, as React team tend to advocate composing more. More can be read here in this tweet by Dan https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/752643494972383232?lang=en

Comment: this is an issue in my project code and its already build. There is a props value in "xyz" which I need in "def" for if-else condition.
Can you suggest some rearrangement?

Answer (score 0):

The way your sample code is written, the constructor in component `def` doesn't accept any `props` -- so calling `super(props)` doesn't actually do anything.

Using vanilla JavaScript, here's an example doing exactly what you're asking for:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}

class HelloExtension extends Hello {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

class XYZ extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Inside XYZ Component</h1>
                <HelloExtension name="World" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <XYZ />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

The only difference in TypeScript is the strong typing of the `props` and `state` interfaces, which you already have in your example.

See a JS fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arthurakay/69z2wepo/98385/).

Comment: Please find the code I pasted. I want the props values from AnalyticsReportsPage in AdvisoryImpactTypePage. 
AdvisoryImpactTypePage is already a child of ChartPage.

Comment: Can you suggest something with refs. I have found few examples where an anonymous component props are fetched by another component.